# Using view share in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

When displaying the code on view it gives an error . Which is:

> Undefined variable: noti_count (View: C:\laravel\Procure\resources\views\layouts\user.blade.php)

I'm not yet used to use view share in controller . Need some guidance:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        if (Auth::User()->role == "Normal User")
        {       
            $noti_count = Notification
                              ::where('receive_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                              ->count();

            view()->share('noti_count', $noti_count);

        }
        else if (Auth::User()->role == "PWD")
        {
            # code...
        }
        elseif (Auth::User()->role == "Senior Citizen")
        {
            # code...
        }
        else
        {       

        }    
    }    
}
```

Blade view code

```
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">{!! $noti_count !!}+</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

`view()->share()` should be used within a service provider's boot.

You can use **AppServiceProvider**, or, make a new provider and don't forget to add it to the end of providers array in **config/app.php**.

**Notice** that when no user is logged in, the `$noti_count` will be undefined. So, you have to check it first:

```
@isset($noti_count)
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">{!! $noti_count !!}+</span>
@endisset
```

Comment: What am i adding in config/app.php ?

Comment: The path of your new service provider if you make one. or you don't have to make any change in **config/app.php** if you use **AppServiceProvider** which come with laravel core.

Comment: I have done adding the view::share('key',value) in appserviceprovider. It still gives the same error.

Comment: @F.ture did you add it exactly like that or you replace the `'key', 'value'` with the actual value?

Comment: @F.ture I add a notice in my answer. check it.

Comment: i added this code in boot function 
public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

Comment: put your code which wrote in **__construct()** not `View::share('key', 'value');`

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 Did my answer bring clarity to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Sharing Data Will All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) section of the documentation. It says:

> ### Sharing Data With All Views
>
> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views
>   that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view
>   facade's `share` method. Typically, you should place calls to `share`
>   within a service provider's `boot` method. You are free to add them to
>   the  `AppServiceProvider` or generate a separate service provider to
>   house them:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Providers;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
>
> class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
> {
>     /**
>      * Register any application services.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function register()
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Bootstrap any application services.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function boot()
>     {
>         View::share('key', 'value');
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, this is helpful to share data accross multiple views. You can do it in your case of course (the documentation is very clear), but if you are gonna do some conditional stuff, why don't return data to the view instead? Like this:

```
public $data;

public function __construct()
{
    if ($condition)
    {
        $this->data = 'Data for first option';
    }
    else if ($condition_two)
    {
        $this->data = 'Some other data';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data = 'Another amount of data';
    }
}
```

Then in a method inside the controller:

```
public function myMethod()
{
    // some stuff

    return view('my_view')->withData($this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct()
{        
    \View::share('key','value');
}
```

Then in blade file:

```
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">{{ $key }}</span>
```